# Another Way to CONCAT in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to concat 3 columns with separator .

Example :

[image]

Result  = TEST, TEST2 (2020)

Someone can help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just express what you want using `||`:

```
select last_name || ' ' || first_name || ' (' || login || ')'
```